# solve the social golfer problem with topic constraint?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

A friend asked me to solve a problem for an event he's organizing. It sounded not too difficult at first, but I'm struggling with it.

The problem:

There will be 100 partecipants, divided into 20 tables of 5 people each. The tables are divided into topics, 5 of them (4 tables for each topic).

A partecipant can't sit in the same topic twice, and he can't be matched with the same persone twice, in order to meet the maximum number of different partecipants possibile.

I've seen the social golfer problem, which is quite similar but I didn't find any solution with the topic-constraint.

Is it doable?

Thank you

ETA to further explain the problem:

Partecipant A needs to visit a table of each topic, without being in a table with the same person twice.

So (assuming all of these tables are of different topics)

if A goes [1,2,3,4,5]

B can't go [1,2,8,10,12]

Because the two would meet the second time on table 2.

Comment: You say only that participants can't be matched with the same person twice -- so apparently they need to be "matched" with other people, multiple times, but you don't give any information about this.

Comment: I'm sorry, probably I didn't explain it correctly - english isn't my first language.

Partecipant A needs to visit a table of each topic, without being in a table with the same person twice.

So (assuming all of these tables are of different topics)

if A goes [1,2,3,4,5]
B can't go [1,2,8,10,12]

Because the two would meet the second time on table 2.

Comment: Thanks, I see now. Could you please edit your original question to add this info?

Comment: I did, thank you for the input. Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, but I suggest looking into [combinatorial designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_design).

Answer (score 0):

I do believe this to be possible. As there are 5 people at each table and only 4 tables designated for a topic, with each shift, you will have 4 of the 5 people move to one topic (each at a different table), and the last move to a completely different topic. This will repeat until everyone has been to each topic.

Comment: How would you guarantee that two people won't meet again?

The second iteration is easy enough, moving each member of a table to a different one of another topic, but then the costraint becomes more difficult